# manually draw a cluster with markerclusterer for maps v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey I'm using the popular markerclusterer plugin for google maps that can be found at http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js

I'm wondering what function I can use to manually add a clustermarker, since I would like, when I zoom out a lot, to cluster the markers serverside before sending a huge load of json over the wire.

**What function is called to add a clustermarker?**

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the lack of any other answer, I made an extension of the MarkerClusterer myself, I'm sure it can be rewritten to a better standard, but this is what I could come up with:

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.AddCluster = function(clat, clng, csize)
{
  var clusterlocation = new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clng)
  var CI = new ClusterIcon(new Cluster(this), this.getStyles, this.getGridSize());
  var index = 0;
  var dv = csize;
  while (dv !== 0) {
    dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
    index++;
  }
  var style = this.styles_[index-1];
  CI.setCenter(clusterlocation);
  $.extend(CI, {sums_ : {text : csize, index: index}, url_ : style['url'], width_ : style['width'], height_ : style['height']});
  CI.setMap(this.map_);
  CI.show();
  CI.triggerClusterClick = function()
  {this.map_.setCenter(clusterlocation);
   this.map_.setZoom(this.map_.getZoom()+1); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted @Jakob's code for the Google Maps API V3.
Hope if can help somebody.

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.A

    ddCluster = function(clat, clng, csize)
    {
        this.setZoomOnClick(false);
        if (typeof this.aAddClusterIcons == "undefined"){
            this.aAddClusterIcons = [];
        }

        this.activeMap_ = this.getMap();
        var clusterlocation = new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clng)
        var CI = new ClusterIcon(new Cluster(this), this.getStyles, this.getGridSize());
        var index = 0;
        var dv = csize;
        while (dv !== 0) {
            dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
            index++;
        }
        var style = this.styles_[index-1];
        $.extend(CI, {sums_ : {text : csize, index: index}, url_ : style['url'], width_ : style['width'], height_ : style['height'], anchorIcon_: [clat, clng]});
        CI.setCenter(clusterlocation);
        CI.setMap(this.activeMap_);
        CI.show();

        this.aAddClusterIcons.push(CI);
    }
    MarkerClusterer.prototype.RemoveClusters = function(clat, clng, csize)
    {
        if (typeof this.aAddClusterIcons == "undefined"){
            this.aAddClusterIcons = [];
        }

        $.each(this.aAddClusterIcons, function(iIndex, oObj){
            oObj.onRemove();
        });
        this.aAddClusterIcons = [];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right you can use the [zoom_changed() event of google map object](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) and i.e. when `map.getZoom()==16` send your json request with a **maxNumberOfFetchedPlaces** parameter so your server can return limited number of results.Since the markerClusterer initialization is like
`var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, fetchedPlacesArray);` you will have no problem.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah that's the functionality to have the MarkerClusterer handle my markers manually, but if I have 10.000 markers in my db, It's waaaaaay to costy to send that data over the wire, let alone have MarkerClusterer make all the calculations, so I want to know how to add a single ClusterMarker, so that I (server-side) can make some calculations and send a clustermarker with no markerdetails over the wire indicating that there are ie. 1532 markers in that cluster. Btw. bounds_changed is better than zoom_changed as it gets when the moves the map around.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.zoom_changed is firing at client side so you can say i.e. "if zoom is 16 i want the server to return 100 results" so yoou make an ajax request to the server with i.e. "url=www.yourdomain.com/getPlaces?number=100;" so your server now knows that must return 100 places in json

Comment: I'm not quite following :) Why would I want to limit the number of markers returned? Wouldn't it make more sense if the data returned was what was actually on the map, but only presented in a less detailed way, as the user would have no way of going through 1532 or even 100 markers anyway. I may be still not getting your point, so please do elaborate :)